# AttributeError: Nonetype - but the variable is a string

Tags: python, python-3.x, attributeerror, nonetype

I am running into a weird Attribute Error on my Python script.

```
 File "/home/francesco/Documents/Dropbox/py_campaigns/queries.py", line 132, in replace_string
string[9] = string[9].replace(' ', '_')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'replace'
>>> string[9]
'displayURL_A'
>>> string[9].replace(' ','_')
'displayURL_A'
```

as you can see I have an attribute error for an element of a list. But when I try the exact same command on the interpreter, everything goes fine. How do I find the object that is None?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You'll need to show more code than that, because when you run your script, `string[9]` is *not* a string. It is `None`.

Comment: the code is pretty long...do you have a rough idea of what you might need to see?

Comment: The place where `string` is assigned (or altered). But you can `print(string)` just before line 132 and see for yourself what it is.

Comment: Anything that involves `string`, i.e., where it passes through and gets altered. You also don't show how you create `string` on the command line, i.e., if that follows the same pattern as in your script.

Comment: Anything that alters `string` would be good. If you can narrow it down yourself, you probably will find the error yourself in the process.

Comment: @LevLevitsky: that will just print 'None'; you'd need to print it at other points in the script as well. And not just the assignement, but anywhere `string` gets modified.

Comment: @Evert The OP currently doesn't believe it'll print `None` :) I agree with your comment, though. Also, `print(string)` will print all elements of `string`, not just `string[9]`, which itself can help understand the problem.

Comment: @LevLevitsky Ok, I hadn't interpreted it as such. And yes, just printing the thing should show where things go wrong, working one's way back up the chain. Old-fashioned debugging.

Comment: ok thanks a lot guys.

    ['S-[_###]: CITY_NAME Hotel E', '[Toa_100|Rcity_###]: Alternativ Hotell', '', '', None, None, None, '', '', None, 'http://www.wimdu.', '0.5']

a function returned 'None'. What was absolutely deceiving was that the interpreter wasn't giving me 'None' on that variable after the error. Maybe someone could clarify on this? I thought that once the error is spotted if you call the variable that gave the error, the last value assigned to it is given. This is why I was so confused!

Comment: Francesco: The value you show for `string` does not correspond to the value of `'displayURL_A'` for `string[9]` either -- so clearly there is a disconnect between `queries.py` running and what you see at the Python console. In fact, it's not clear how you got from one to the other without losing the value of `string` in the process.

Comment: I get 'None' after some elements in the string list are altered in a custom function. When I print string[9], somehow the interpreter returns the value of that element of the list before being altered by the function

Answer (score 0):

Try with below lines, it will not throw any errors

```
x= string[9] and string[9].replace(' ', '_')
```

Answer (score 0):

If seen similar errors when an exception is raised inside a `with block` that modifies some variable on exit. 
By the time you get the control of the interpreter after the exception all the context managers are closed and some variables could have different values.

It's possible that this is your case?